# If I set up a Heroku custom domain, will it still be accessible under its herokuapp.com address?

Tags: heroku

If I have a site at myapp.herokuapp.com and I set it up have a custom domain of app.mydomain.com, will it still be accessible at myapp.herokuapp.com in addition to the custom domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by default you'll be able to access it from both locations...